# CASSANDRA_PORT_9042_TCP_ADDR in Cassandra docker image

Tags: docker, cassandra

I am new to Cassandra and I started learning it using Docker containers. For docker image, I am referring to https://hub.docker.com/_/cassandra/ which provides an official Cassandra docker image.

The **Connect to Cassandra from cqlsh** section in the page uses

```
exec cqlsh "$CASSANDRA_PORT_9042_TCP_ADDR"
```

while connecting through cqlsh. The variable `$CASSANDRA_PORT_9042_TCP_ADDR` contains the ip address of the original Cassandra container. I was searching about the variable `CASSANDRA_PORT_9042_TCP_ADDR` but I am not able to find where it is getting defined and how.

I also looked into Cassandra documentation but did not find anything over there also. I also grep'd into the entire Cassandra container.  Can anyone please provide more detailed information about the environment variable?

Answer (score 2):

This variable is automatically created by Docker when you link with other container.  It has the format of `<name>_PORT_<port>_<protocol>`, where `<name>` is `CASSANDRA`, and default port is 9042...  See the [Docker documentation](http://%3Cname%3E_PORT_%3Cport%3E_%3Cprotocol%3E) for more details.

But it could be simpler to run `cqlsh` directly in already running container instead of creating a new instance & link it to Cassandra container.  Just execute:

```
docker exec -ti <container_name_or_hash> cqlsh
```